# Can all problems that can be solved by greedy also be solved by dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm

If an optimal solution to a problem can be obtained by greedy, can it also be obtained by dynamic programming? Since both greedy and dp are dealing with the optimal solution to the sub-problems, is it safe to say that dp can solve all the problems that can be solved by greedy?

Comment: First define "optimal".

Comment: Unfortunately this question is meaningless because dynamic programming is not a formal classification of algorithms.  Greedy algorithms are, however. Read up on the theory of matroids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing Greedy and DP is like comparing oranges to apples.  But an easy way to think is

**Greedy approach:** Choose whatever you think is optimal now, **assuming** it will be optimal in the long run.
For example when you are driving and see traffic jam on one road you may take an alternate road which looks empty. This may work but the alternate road can have more severe traffic jam around the corner.

**Dynamic Programming** on the other hand uses memory to store calculations/results that you have done previously to save time the next time you need them. Using above problem again, The DP Solution would be to calculate traffic on every road and then choose the road(s) which gives best (optimal) time.

In this sense DP is more like a **Divide and Conquer** approach but **with memory**. You do not calculate results of **sub problems** again and again.

And to answer your question

> is it safe to say that dp can solve all the problems that can be solved by greedy

I think it is safe to say dp can solve all the problems divide and conquer can solve (may take more memory though)

Of all the examples I can think of **DP can give optimal solutions** for questions that can be solved optimally by greedy (DP may take **exponential time** though and almost in each case DP will take more memory).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the similarity between DP and divide and conquer, but thought DP and greedy are quite the same thing. And I also think dp can give optimal solution to all problems that greedy can, though no textbook says so.